# Python: global name "treeInsert" is not defined - recursive

Tags: python, recursion, nameerror

I have the following code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, key):
         self.key = key
         self.left = None
         self.right = None

    def treeInsert(rootnode, key):
         if rootnode is None:
             return Node(key)
         if rootnode.key == key:
             return rootnode
         elif key < rootnode.key:     
             rootnode.left = treeInsert(rootnode.left, key)
         else:
             rootnode.right = treeInsert(rootnode.right, key)
         return rootnode
```

If I now want to use the `treeInsert` method, I get the following error:

> NameError: global name 'treeInsert' is not defined.

Comment: wrong indentation? `treeInsert` should be without indentation if it's not part of `Node` class.

Comment: Originally, tabs were used, so the display was wrong. The original text made it clear that `treeInsert` was part of the `Node` class, so either it needed to be a static method, rewritten as a proper instance method, or moved out of the class altogether to be a true function.

Comment: ...or there should be a separate `Tree` class that holds the root node and contains a method like `insert`.

Comment: Thanks :)

Well that code is 1:1 from our professor, he wanted to call it rootnode... now that makes sense.
but if i now call the function, it says i'm giving 3 arguments allthough treeInsert can only take 2:
rootnode.left = rootnode.treeInsert(rootnode.left, key)

OK!!!
I think your comments were a great help; I started with C++ and now we use Python... I were putting the functions into the class because I was used to it. I didn't think about it too much!

Answer (score 2):

`treeInsert` is not a global name, but a method of the `Node` class. As written, you should make it a static method, and refer to it as `Node.treeInsert`.

```
@staticmethod
def treeInsert(rootnode, key):
     if rootnode is None:
         return Node(key)
     if rootnode.key == key:
         return rootnode
     elif key < rootnode.key:     
         rootnode.left = Node.treeInsert(rootnode.left, key)
     else:
         rootnode.right = Node.treeInsert(rootnode.right, key)
     return root node
```

Better yet, make it a proper instance method, something like

```
def treeInsert(self, key):
    if self.key == key:
        return key
    elif key < self.key:
        return (self.left or Node(key)).treeInsert(key)
    else:
        return (self.right or Node(key)).treeInsert(key)
```